# SqlAlchemy / PyMySQL: AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX' on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, driver, pymysql

So I think I know where this error comes from. I'm using

```
query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})
```

as my connection string, as per the tutorial I followed. However, in my searches I found that Python doesn't support Unix sockets. Do I need to change the query_string or socket type? And if so, to what?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Connection code:

```
driver_name = 'mysql+pymysql'
query_string = dict({"unix_socket": "/cloudsql/{}".format(connection_name)})
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername=driver_name,
            username=db_user,
            password=db_password,
            database=db_name,
            query=query_string,
        ),
        pool_size=5,
        max_overflow=2,
        pool_timeout=30,
        pool_recycle=1800
    )
    results = None
    with db.connect() as conn:
        results = conn.execute(stmt)
        return resultToData(results)
```

Error is thrown in `AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py, line 600.`

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
```

EDIT:
I also looked at the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html?highlight=unix), but couldn't really find a solution there either.

Comment: [This document](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/cloud-sql/mysql/sqlalchemy/README.md#running-locally) states "on Windows the [cloudsql] proxy currently requires a TCP connection."

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Thanks! I'll start looking for another solution then.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I tried running it on a Linux machine, but then I got (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'. ([Errno 2])) while I'm not trying to connect to localhost, but to Cloud SQL. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: hi @antonioACR1, replying from my other (main) account. I'm not sure if or how I fixed it because it's been so long ago. Maybe there's been some new module releases in the past 2 years which can help you. Best of luck!
EDIT: I think in the end I moved everything to be hosted in the Google Cloud (which is what I was trying to connect to), which fixed the problem. I no longer have access to that project however, so I can't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks @JasperMW , just one last question. Did you use Docker container to host your project in Google Cloud?

Comment: @antonioACR1 I used a Linux VM running Python to host it since I had no experience with Docker back then. I think Docker would be a cleaner solution however, and would recommend it over a VM.